# How could I make this numerical integral precise?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am attempting to compute a numerical integral but I seem to not get the desired numerical stability. The integral in question is

```
num[c_, w_, prec_, rec_] := NIntegrate[
    SetPrecision[(y^((2*π)/11*(1/w - c) + 1)*E^-y)/(1-(y*11*w)/(2*π)),prec+1],
    {y,0,SetPrecision[(2*π)/11*1/w,prec+1],∞},
    WorkingPrecision->prec,
    MinRecursion->rec,
    Method-> "PrincipalValue"
]
```

for instance, if I evaluate

```
num[1, 0.1, 30, 3]=-145.67943817523307026331395062
```

where I get many error messages. But If I increase the working precision and the amount of minimal recursion I instead get

```
num[1, 0.1, 40, 4]=-10171.12237422827887743490803771360414548
```

which is totally different from the previous result. I have attempted going to higher values in the arguments prec and rec but I do not get any kind of stability. I think I am making a suboptimal use of NIntegrate. I have attempted reading the NIntegrate pages online, and I have attempted playing with AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but I haven't really obtained any improvement. How should I improve my expression?

Comment: You call `num` it with exact input: `num[1, 1/10, 40, 3]`. Or, in the body of `num`, set the precision of the inputs to higher precision before submitting them to `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to feed [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) exact values, and allow [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) to approximate as necessary. So:

```
num[c_, w_, opts:OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := NIntegrate[
    (y^((2*π)/11*(1/w-c)+1)*E^-y)/(1-(y*11*w)/(2*π)),
    {y, 0, 2 π/(11 w), ∞},
    Method -> "PrincipalValue",
    opts
];
```

For your sample input:

```
num[1, 1/10, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

> -666.3617050447222935780196636918737896573472951093 + 0.*10^-47 I